# using dummy arguments to assist template specialisation

Tags: templates, design-patterns, c++11

I am coding something where I ended up having to use dummy arguments to implement template specialisation since you can't overload on the return type. I'm wondering if this is correct, i.e. others have done it, or if there's a better way to do it.

```
namespace ObjectDetail
{
template <typename T>
inline T get(Object&, int, T&);

template <>
inline std::string get(void* handle, int index, std::string& unused) // dummy argument.
{
    return somelib_get_string(handle, index);
}

template <>
inline int get(void* handle, int index, int& unused) // dummy argument.
{
    return somelib_get_int(handle, index);
}
} // namespace ObjectDetail

class Object
{
public:
    std::string getString(int index) const
    {
        std::string unused;   // dummy variable.
        return ObjectDetail::get(m_handle, index, unused);
    }

    int getInt(int index) const
    {
        int unused;  // dummy variable.
        return ObjectDetail::get(m_handle, index, unused);
    }

private:
    void* m_handle;
}
```

I'm also hoping the compiler (gcc 4.6.3) is intelligent enough to figure out that the dummy arguments aren't actually used.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine. I would rather use few dummy tag types:

```
class classA {};
class classB {};
class classC {};
```

and use them instead of int, string etc.

and then do

```
return ObjectDetail::get(m_handle, index, classC());
```

You may also put these tag types in a namespace and name them more logically.